# How to fetch data from one model and display it in the form as drop down for storing it in another model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have a 3 models namely category, brand, products. i have to include the category and brand in the products form for displaying it in drop down and selected value should be assigned in the products table.can anyone help me with it?

Comment: please share some code regarding how much you have tried

Comment: class Products(models.Model):
 pname=models.CharField(max_length=10)
 pcode=models.CharField(max_length=5)
 category=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 brand=models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 supplier=models.CharField(max_length=50)
 description=models.CharField(max_length=50)

 class Meta:
  db_table="products"                                                                                 this is what i did for product model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you have a three models.  Category, Brand, Products.

## models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    #
    # Your logic here
    #

class Brand(models.Model):
    #
    # Your logic here
    #

class Products(models.Model):
    #
    # Your logic here
    #
```

Now generate forms based on models (using `ModelForm`) or just use `Form` class.

## forms.py

```
class CategoryModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__' # for example

class BrandForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = '__all__' # for example
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cf = CategoryForm(data=request.POST)
        bf = BrandForm(data=request.POST)
        if cf.is_valid() and bf.is_valid(): # validate both form together
            # cf.cleaned_data and bf.cleaned_data returns validated data.
            print('CategoryForm valid data => ', cf.cleaned_data)
            print('BrandForm valid data => ', bf.cleaned_data)
            Products.objects.create(field1=cf.cleaned_data['some_field'], field2=bf.cleaned_data['some_field']) # you should implement your own logic. Performs database insert query.
            return JsonResponse({'status_message': 'Successfully updated Products table'})
    else:
        cf = CategoryForm()
        bf = BrandForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'cf': cf, 'bf': bf})
```

## index.html

```
<form accept="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ cf.as_p }} <br />
    {{ bf.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="click" />
</form>
```

I hope it will helps you !

Comment: Make ProductForm validation also. Why you can not do this ? so easy

Comment: this is ok but i have a third form ProductForm. In that i have to display the values from Category table and brand table

Comment: yes, and why not to make validation of ProductForm also ?

Comment: sorry,i didn't get you

Comment: i tried so many methods ,but nothing works. My question is simple, i have to fetch the data from table and display it in dropdown box in a form.On saving the form,i should store the selected value in the another table.